# How to edit javascript chronometer display style

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the following javascript to include a chronometer on my website, which is started by clicking an associated button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ore=0;
    var minuti=0;
    var secondi=0;
    var decimi=0;
    var visualizzazione="";
    var contatore_intertempi=0;
    var stop=1; //0=attivo 1=fermo

    function avvia(){
        if (stop==1){
            stop=0;
            cronometro();
        }
    }

function cronometro(){
    if (stop==0) {
        decimi+=1;
        if (decimi>9) {decimi=0;secondi+=1;}
        if (secondi>59) {secondi=0;minuti+=1;}
        if (minuti>59) {minuti=0;ore+=1;}
        if (ore<10) {visualizzazione="0" + ore;
        } else {visualizzazione=ore;}
        if (minuti<10) {visualizzazione=visualizzazione + ":0" + minuti;
        } else {visualizzazione=visualizzazione + ":" + minuti;}
        if (secondi<10) {visualizzazione=visualizzazione + ":0" + secondi;
        } else {visualizzazione=visualizzazione + ":" + secondi;}
        visualizzazione=visualizzazione;
        document.getElementById("mostra_cronometro").value=visualizzazione;
        setTimeout("cronometro()", 100);
    }
}

</script>
```

The problem is the bad graphics with which the counter is shown: currently I'm calling it with `<input id="mostra_cronometro" value="00:00:00"/>` but I don't like the style.
So I tried to make it like this `<div id="mostra_cronometro" value="00:00:00">` but it doesn't seem to work with the JS now.

Is there anyway to make it work without using the `<input>` thing, so I can customize the graphics?

Comment: `div` elements don't support the `value` attribute. You can't simply replace the tag of the element and expect the functionality to remain unaffected.

Comment: oh I see, any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `div` but you will have to change the `value` property with `innerText`.

```html
<div id="mostra_cronometro">00:00:00</div>
<button onclick="avvia()"> Start</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ore=0;
var minuti=0;
var secondi=0;
var decimi=0;
var visualizzazione="";
var contatore_intertempi=0;
var stop=1; //0=attivo 1=fermo

function avvia(){
if (stop==1){
stop=0;
cronometro();}}

function cronometro(){
  if (stop==0) {
    decimi+=1;
    if (decimi>9) {decimi=0;secondi+=1;}
    if (secondi>59) {secondi=0;minuti+=1;}
    if (minuti>59) {minuti=0;ore+=1;}
    if (ore<10) {visualizzazione="0" + ore;} else {visualizzazione=ore;}
    if (minuti<10) {visualizzazione=visualizzazione + ":0" + minuti;} else {visualizzazione=visualizzazione + ":" + minuti;}
    if (secondi<10) {visualizzazione=visualizzazione + ":0" + secondi;} else {visualizzazione=visualizzazione + ":" + secondi;}
    visualizzazione=visualizzazione;
    document.getElementById("mostra_cronometro").innerText = visualizzazione;
    setTimeout("cronometro()", 100);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your code by filling digits with zeroes at the beginning by
`('00' + number).slice(-2);` instead of `if (number<10) ...`